# Aes for React web application for encryption

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement aes type encryption and decryption in my react web application. I found many react native libraries for the same but no library for web application. Any help on what can be used?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does encryption have to do with React?

Comment: I need to encrypt text in my react web application. Is there any specific react library for the same?

Comment: React is a UI library, how is it in any way related to encryption? You want a javascript AES library.